# Allocating a C struct in JavaScript with emscripten

Tags: javascript, emscripten

I'm trying to call `SDL_GetDisplayMode` https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetDisplayMode from JavaScript. The function is exported and can be called correctly with `Module.ccall`, but I'm not sure how to create the `SDL_DisplayMode` struct so I can hand a pointer to it off to the function.

From reading, it seems this is done with typed arrays by calling Module._malloc: http://kapadia.github.io/emscripten/2013/09/13/emscripten-pointers-and-pointers.html However, it is not clear how the JS alone can determine the size of a struct in order to allocate memory for it.

Answer (score 0):

You should determine the size of your struct yourself since the sizeof() function is executed during the compilation. You can know the size of your struct with a sizeof(SDL_DisplayMode) compiled with Emscripten.